# Getting selected items count ListBox with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

As in topic - how to get selected items count in ListBox with jQuery, while user is selecting new item?

I have these code:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(x => Model.StatesID, Model.States,
        new { @class = "chzn-select", @id="StatesID", data_placeholder = "Choose...", style = "width:350px;" })


function countStates() {
    var count = $("#StatesID:selected").length;
    alert(count);

}
```

I can get count of selected items in `onclick` input action, but how to connect this js function with `onclick` event, or maybe other event, when user is selecting new item in my listbox?

Comment: Is the ID for the ListBox `StatesID` or `statesMailing`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding my comment as answer....

If it is a multi-select, you will want to use....

```
$('#StatesID').on('change', function(){
    countStates();
});
```

otherwise click does not fire if the user selects more that one option at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#StatesID').click(countStates);
});
```

Comment: If it is a milti-select, you will want to use `$('#StatesID').on('change', function(){countStates();});` otherwise click does not fire if the user selects more that one option at a time.