# Count Number of Selected Items in ListBox

Tags: jquery, listbox

I have a listbox:

```
<div>
  <select id="SelectBox" multiple>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

This listbox is allowing for multiple selections.  All I am trying to do is count the number of selected items.

Here is my jQuery:

```
$("#SelectBox").change(function(){
    countSelectedItems();
});

function countSelectedItems(){
    var count = $("#SelectBox:selected").length;
  alert(count);
}
```

I have researched this solution from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17885615/getting-selected-items-count-listbox-with-jquery), but it is not working.  I continue to keep being alerted with `0`.

Here is my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/42urLod3/1/).

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are counting the number of elements with the ID "SelectBox" that are selected. What you want to do is count the number of `<option>` elements that are children of the "SelectBox" that are selected, like so:

```
#SelectBox > option:selected
```

```js
$(function(){

  $('#debug').text( "number of selected options: " + $('#SelectBox > option:selected').length );

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="SelectBox" multiple>
<option selected>foo</option>
<option selected>bar</option>
<option>baz</option>
</select>

<div id="debug"></div>
```

Comment: ahh gotcha okay.  Thank you.

Comment: OP's  select only contains options , so additionally looking for options and then the :selected is extra work ...

Comment: @Exception_al - the difference is trivial, but the code is a lot clearer. You should optimize for programmer time except where the code bottleneck is significant. Don't optimize prematurely.

Comment: @bville be careful not to substantially change your question. If you have another question, create a new post. I believe the current answers correctly and sufficiently address the original question.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a space between the selectors :)

```
var count = $("#SelectBox :selected").length;
```

Look at the selector [Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/)

Comment: Also a good point. I still prefer clearer code, but it's good to understand the difference a space can make.

Answer (score 2):

You need to separate the pseudo element `:selected` from the `#SelectBox`. When you use `:selected` pseudo selector you can use it plain as it is or on a `option` element, not on the `select` directly.

```js
$("#SelectBox").change(function() {
  countSelectedItems();
}).change();

function countSelectedItems() {
  var count = $("#SelectBox :selected").length;
  //console.log(count);
  $('#count span').text(count);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <select id="SelectBox" multiple>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
  <p id='count'>The count is: <span></span></p>
</div>
```